# Relative angles on unknown surface

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm hoping someone here could help me with a problem I am having. I have an electronic sensor that measures tilt, and I put this sensor on a 10 degree ramp. The problem is that this portable ramp is put on surfaces that the levelness is unknown. It can vary up to +/- six degrees. The bottom of the ramps are perfectly flat, and the ramp angle is always 10 degrees accurate to 15 arc-seconds.

Here is the procedure I use, first I put the sensor on the surface to take an angle measurement. I store this measurement, then the user places the ramp on the surface, and the sensor on the 10 degree ramp surface.

The Problem

The user can place the ramp any direction on the surface, and the surface and be "unlevel" any direction such as -5 degrees or +2 degrees, etc.

Here is a quick mspaint picture (The triangle 10 degrees are not to scale, they look more like 45 degrees (sorry)):
[image: Ramps on unknown surfaces]

The two main situations I'm most concerned about are:

Case 1:

The green ramp is placed so that the "high" portion of the ramp is set on a surface sloping low to high. So the surfaces low angle subtracts from what the sensor will read on the 10 degree ramp (Blue curly bracket under ramp)

Case 2:

The yellow ramp is placed so that the "high portion of the ramp is set on the surface sloping  high to low so the surface adds to the angle measured by the sensor on the 10 degree ramp surface. (orange curly bracket under ramp)

I want to mathematically "zero" this surface out so it has no effect on the 10 degree ramp measurement by the sensor. Right now I'm just measuring the surface angle and subtracting it from the measurement of the 10 degree ramp for a relative angle. Plus this gets messed up if I need to add the surface angle or subtract it. Am I right in this line of thought?

I wanted to know if there is a better way to do this so if the user places the ramp in any direction of the surface I can zero it out so the sensor could read the 10 degree ramp without having the surface affect the measurement.

Thinking there might be a trig solution..

The sensor is a single axis sensor, so it should be easier I would think

Thank you